# different results using quaternion and Euler angles

Tags: matlab, quaternions, coordinate-systems, euler-angles

I am using two methods to rotate a point `p0` (a vector) in 3D space. I have the world coordinate system (WCS), shown in black, and coordinate system 1 (CS1), shown in blue, which is defined to be rotated by 10 degrees around z-axis. I first calculate the directional cosine between WCS and CS1, by calculating dot products. Now I can easily calculate both the quaternion and the Euler angles using `dcm2quat` and `dcm2angle`. Then I can rotate the point `p0` using both quaternion and Euler angles.

```
p0  = [1 0 0]; % point in world CS
ijk = [1 0 0;0 1 0;0 0 1];
uvw1 = [0.9848 0.1736 0;-0.1736 0.9848 0;0 0 1.0000]; % CS1
DC01 = [dot(uvw1(1,:),ijk(1,:)) dot(uvw1(1,:),ijk(2,:)) dot(uvw1(1,:),ijk(3,:))
        dot(uvw1(2,:),ijk(1,:)) dot(uvw1(2,:),ijk(2,:)) dot(uvw1(2,:),ijk(3,:))
        dot(uvw1(3,:),ijk(1,:)) dot(uvw1(3,:),ijk(2,:)) dot(uvw1(3,:),ijk(3,:))];

[rz, ry, rx] = dcm2angle(DC01,'ZYX'); 
q1 = dcm2quat(DC01);

p1_1 = quatrotate(q1,p0);
p1_2 = (rotz(rz*180/pi)*roty(ry*180/pi)*rotx(rx*180/pi)*p0').';
```

But at the end the results are different:

```
p1_1 = 
    0.9848   -0.1736         0
p1_2 =
    0.9848    0.1736         0
```

I understand that using Euler angles can result in gimbal lock and make ambiguity, but in this case the result obtained using quaternion is not correct while the result obtained from the Euler angles is. What am I missing?

The following image shows CS1 (blue), WCS (black), `p0` (black), `p1_1` (blue), `p1_2` (red).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB:

If I use directional cosine or the quaternion in order to rotate the point, I am actually rotating the reference frame:

```
pdc = (DC01*p0')'    % rotation using directional cosine matrix
pdc =

    0.9848   -0.1736         0
```

equivalent to:

```
p1_1 = quatrotate(q1,p0);
p1_1 = 

     0.9848   -0.1736         0
```

On the other hand, using Euler angles and rotation matrices, I can rotate a point (a vector) w.r.t a coordinate system:

```
p1_2 = (rotz(rz*180/pi)*roty(ry*180/pi)*rotx(rx*180/pi)*p0').';
p1_2 =

    0.9848    0.1736         0
```

**Conclusion:** 
Using quaternion or directional cosine matrix, we rotate the coordinate systems while the point (vector) stays fixed. Whereas, using rotation matrices we are able to rotate a vector w.r.t a coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

I  have  encountered  same  phenomenon  with  you  when 
I  use  dcm  and  quaternion  to  rotate  a  vector.

We  can  consider  WCS  as  the  only  one  reference.  Abovementioned  DCM  rotates  a vector  counterclockwisely,  quaternion  rotates  a vector clockwisely.